# Encoding problem with HTTP request from VBA to flask

Tags: python, excel, vba, flask, character-encoding

I'm doing POST request from VBA containing some cyrillic characters from Cells(1, 1) to my flask app like this:

```vb
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
URL = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/lineList?line=" & Cells(1, 1).Value
objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
objHTTP.send ("")
```

In flask i try to output arguments with the following:

```py
    def post(self):
        args = parser.parse_args()
        print(args)
        return "ok",200
```

But then i get something like

```
{'line': 'Ð\x90Ñ\x80Ð³Ñ\x83Ð¼ÐµÐ½Ñ\x82'}
```

And in python console

```
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Apr/2019 17:10:31] "POST /lineList?line=ÐÑÐ³ÑÐ¼ÐµÐ½Ñ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Looks like some encoding problem, but i can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define charset for cyrillic, try some of this:

```
charset=iso-8859-5
charset=koi8-r
charset=windows-1251
```

e.g:

```
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "charset=ISO-8859-1"
```

Comment: Tried all of it, nothing changes at all.

Comment: Where is the output supposed to display correctly? Can you display the cyrillic characters correctly in a VBA console (Immediate window)?

Comment: Yes, Immediate displays the characters correctly. It's "Аргумент" in this case.